# query for count data with status and id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, mysqli

```
S.no  |   j_id  |age | status |
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     2   |32  |  1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |      2   |32  |  2     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     1   |32  |  3     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
 1    |     3   |32  |  1     |
------------------------------------
```

i m using this query to get the count of status 1 for the particular j_id but i am getting wrong result what i am doing wrong here can anyone please help me related this...

Comment: What is your current query that you wrote?

Comment: @php $res['count_active']=DB::select('SELECT count(status) as active_total FROM `tbl_workers_details` WHERE status = 1 AND job_title_id = ".$jobtitle->id." '); @endphp

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: i want status count 2 for the j_id 1 an so .on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this.

Using SQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) as total 
FROM table_name 
WHERE status=1
    AND j_id = $yourChosenId
```

This will get count of all data with status 1 and your chosen id

Also, you also have a tag of Laravel so I think these would help you also.

If you're going to use query builder:

```
DB::table('table_name')
    ->where('status','=',1)
    ->where('j_id','=',$yourChosenId)
    ->count();
```

Using Eloquent:

```
ModelName::where('status','=',1)
    ->where('j_id','=',$yourChosenId)
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the status 1 count for all the users do:

```
SELECT j_id, COUNT(*) as active_total 
FROM tbl_workers_details WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY j_id;
```

But if you want it for a particular user then you should specify the id like below:

```
SELECT j_id, COUNT(*) as active_total 
FROM tbl_workers_details WHERE status = 1
AND j_id=1;
```